# Different height menu need to be placed vertically centered of their parents div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Could you please help me to set the dropdown menu position vertically centered of their parents (orange) divs? Right now they are showing up from the top edge of the parent div. I want dropdown position exactly same as shown in below screenshot. You will see dropdown when you hover on the orange boxes.

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/ozdt2z6z/2/)

[image]

**code:**

```
.parent{
width:100px; height:100px;
background:orange;
position:relative;
margin-right:100px;
float:left;
margin-bottom:80px;
}
.parent:hover .child{display:block;}
.parent .child{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    display:none;
    }
.parent .child ul{    
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    background:#262626;
    }
    .parent .child ul li{
        padding:5px;
        font:normal 12px arial;
        border:1px solid black;
        background:#464646;
        color:#fff;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done just using CSS3

```
.child {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozdt2z6z/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a jquery solution, try this:

```
$('.parent').on('mouseover', function(){
  var ph = $(this).height();
  var $ch = $(this).find('.child');
  var ht = $ch.height();
  var offset = ph/2 -ht/2;
  $ch.css('top', offset);
});
```

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ozdt2z6z/5/)